# Boolean Logic- Choosing true value for outputs

Tags: c#

I am currently working with Boolean logic and truth tables. I have been able to create a class that will generate a 2 variable`(a,b)` table. My main interest is choosing certain inputs in the table and setting a ‘true’ value for its output. I have been able to hard code the above mentioned through `override bool GetTruthValue()` and display those `true` value output results in a multiline textbox called `OutputTextBox`. I want the logic of calculating the truth value to be provided by user. My current approach the logic is being provided by the code. How can I have the user pick which input’s will have an output value of `true? Indicate through checkboxes or separate texboxes(with 1 or 0)? Or other suggestions?

```
namespace table_outputs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public abstract class TwoItemTruthRow
        {
            protected TwoItemTruthRow(bool a, bool b)
            {
                A = a; B = b;
            }

            public bool A { get; protected set; }
            public bool B { get; protected set; }

            public abstract bool GetTruthValue();
        }

    public class MyCustomTwoItemTruthRow : TwoItemTruthRow
        {
            public MyCustomTwoItemTruthRow(bool a, bool b)
                : base(a, b)
            {
            }

            public override bool GetTruthValue()
            {
                // My custom logic- Hard coded
                return (A && B) || (A && !B) || (!A && !B);
            }
        }

    private static string GetHorizontalLineText()
        {
            return "-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
        }
        private static string GetFormattedTwoItemText(MyCustomTwoItemTruthRow item)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\t{1}\r\n", item.A, item.B);
        }

    private static IEnumerable<MyCustomTwoItemTruthRow> GenerateTruthTableTwo()
        {
            for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++)
                for (var b = 0; b < 2; b++)
                    yield return new MyCustomTwoItemTruthRow(
                        Convert.ToBoolean(a),
                        Convert.ToBoolean(b));
        }

    private void GenerateTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputTextBox.Clear();
            InputTextBox.Text += "A\tB\r\n";
            InputTextBox.Text += GetHorizontalLineText();

            var myTruthTable = GenerateTruthTable().ToList();
            foreach (var item in myTruthTable)
            {
                InputTextBox.Text += GetFormattedTwoItemText(item);
                InputTextBox.Text += GetHorizontalLineText();
            }
        }
        private void ShowTrueValuesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OutputTextBox.Clear();
            OutputTextBox.Text += "True Values\r\n";
            OutputTextBox.Text += "A\tB\r\n";
            OutputTextBox.Text += GetHorizontalLineText();

            var myTruthTable = GenerateTruthTableTwo().ToList();
            foreach (var item in myTruthTable)
            {

                if (item.GetTruthValue())
                    OutputTextBox.Text += GetFormattedTwoItemText(item);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**Current WinForm**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a list of objects to a `DataGridView` on your form and create columns for each of the input and output fields.  Using `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` for the columns gives you a set of check boxes that the user can interact with.  Set ReadOnly on the input columns, and maybe change the background color to indicate that they are fixed.

You can either define the columns dynamically or create as many columns as you might ever need and hide the ones you're not using.  Depends on how you want to define the data you're attaching them to more than anything.

Here's a mockup I did in VS2010:

[image]

This is bound to a list of the following object type:

```
public class TruthTableEntry
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
    public bool Out { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the form code for my mockup:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<TruthTableEntry> table;

    public Form1()
    {
        // generate a 3-input truth table (8 input variations)
        table = GenerateTruthTable(3);

        // setup DataGridView
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "A";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "B";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "C";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "D";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Out";
        // hide column 3 ('D') as unused
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
}

// Create a truth table for 1-4 inputs
static List<TruthTableEntry> GenerateTruthTable(int numInputs)
{
    // range-check number of inputs
    if (numInputs < 1 || numInputs > 4)
        return null;

    // calculate number of input states
    int permutations = 1 << numInputs;

    // create result list of input states
    List<TruthTableEntry> res = new List<TruthTableEntry>();
    for (int i = 0; i < permutations; ++i)
    {
        // use bit manipulation to initialize a TruthTableEntry:
        TruthTableEntry ent = new TruthTableEntry 
            {
                A = (i & (1 >> (NumInputs - 1))) != 0,
                B = (i & (1 >> (NumInputs - 2))) != 0,
                C = (i & (1 >> (NumInputs - 3))) != 0,
                D = (i & (1 >> (NumInputs - 4))) != 0,
                Out = false,
            };
        res.Add(ent);
    }
    return res;
}
```

`dataGridView1` is a `DataGridView` with 5 `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` columns defined, with first 4 columns set to ReadOnly and colored.

Comment: +1 This is great. Although i know its a mock up. But can you elaborate more on this answer so it can be a working example. I am having difficulties getting this part working: ` List<TruthTableEntry> table;` and `table = GenerateTruthTable(3);` in my form

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dynamic DataGridView with a separate textbox for indicating the number of variables.

The default value can be 2 variables and on launch a DataGridView would be generated as your truth table with an extra last column for editing the desired output of each row.

If the user changes the number of variables, adjust your DataGridView accordingly.  (You may want to add a button to change the DataGridView)

Whatever the case, I would suggest aiming for the interface to require the least amount of clicks/keystrokes as possible.